# Want to real image is clickable but should not click the alpha background. Please suggest me how can i do this

Tags: react-native

i'm facing a problem in react native 
Want to  real image is clickable  but should not click  the alpha background. Please suggest me how can i do this.

In below image i used zIndex to placing the birds ,red color indicate the alpha area of above bird[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCWSc.png)

Comment: Maybe try to make css polygon similar to those birds that is transparent?

Comment: what you really want is to make the red portion clickable, right?, I think wrapping the view with TouchableHighlight may help u, please share some piece of code

Comment: want to click through red portion so that user should able to click back bird

all birds are clickable. problem is image has rectangle shape (Real content and other part is alpha).so above bird image (Alpha portion cover the below image now user are not able to click below bird image).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this with React Native. The best solution I've found is by defining SVGs and using [`react-native-svg`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg), which supports [touch events](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#touch-events). If you're using Expo, then it is already preinstalled and can be imported like `import { Svg } from 'expo'; const { Circle, Rect } = Svg;`.

Alternatively, you may be able to use a [`WebView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview) [(mirror)](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) and CSS masking to achieve your desired result.